# No method or default for coercing "sf" to "SpatialPoints"

Tags: qgis, shapefile, r

I keep getting the below error message when I try to use R in QGIS.  For example Monte Carlo or Quadrant.

I use a point shape file with the x and y coordinates as centroids within the attribute table.

For example

```
##Point pattern analysis=group
##Layer=vector point
##Simulations=number 100
##Optional_plot_name=string
##showplots
library(spatstat)
library(maptools)
sp <- as(Layer, "SpatialPoints")
sp <- as(sp, "ppp")
e <- envelope(sp, Kest, nsim = Simulations)
>e
plot(e, main = Optional_plot_name)
```

Error Message

```
Error in as(Layer, "SpatialPoints") :
no method or default for coercing "sf" to "SpatialPoints"
Calls: as -> .class1 -> as
```

Info on the point shapefile as follows

```
Name
LandScanJoinCTAT
Path
G:\Article\GIS\LandScan\Master\LandScanJoinCTAT.shp
Storage
ESRI Shapefile
Comment

Encoding
System
Geometry
Point (Point)
CRS
EPSG:4326 - WGS 84 - Geographic
Extent
17.0590112291777913,-34.4981314092633582 : 32.5317232060707155,-22.4313408665917606
Unit
degrees
Feature count
234
```

Comment: There is no method for this. Instead use `as(x, "Spatial")` which will result in a SpatialPointsDataFrame, as it should. If you need aSpatialPoints object you can coerce using `coordinates`

Comment: It looks like QGIS is passing vector data (here `Layer`) as `sf` objects instead of `sp` objects. I don't know when that happened or who wrote the analysis script being run here (wasn't me).

Comment: @Spacedman The rsx code is still available [here](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Processing/tree/master/rscripts).

Answer (score 1):

Latest version of [Processing R Provider](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/processing_r/) allows us to choose between `sf` and `rgdal` to load vector data, and `sf` is the default provider (from version 2.0, I guess).

You may follow the suggestion by @Jeffrey Evans, or add `##load_vector_using_rgdal` option to use `rgdal` instead of `sf`; for instance -

```
##Point pattern analysis=group
##load_vector_using_rgdal 
##Layer=vector point
##Simulations=number 100
##Optional_plot_name=string
##showplots
library(spatstat)
library(maptools)
sp <- as(Layer, "SpatialPoints")
sp <- as(sp, "ppp")
e <- envelope(sp, Kest, nsim = Simulations)
>e
plot(e, main = Optional_plot_name)
```

It's the second line.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.  I have used your advise and it seems to work.  However I found another solution.  I save the shape-files in csv via QGIS, then transfer the csv file into R and then use R to create another shape-file (similar to the original). I then open the R created shape-file in QGIS And it works fine.  But only for point layers and files